# How to render mixed json results in need for different templates (with distinct variables) using angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I wonder what is the best practice when I have a response that has many different types of objects and looks like that:

```
[
{"nodeClass":"Entity", "text":"foo","entityfield":"booz"},
{"nodeClass":"User","username":"bar","userfield":"baz"}
]
```

and I have different templates for all of those:

for Entities:

```
<div class="{{nodeClass}} capsule">{{entity.text}}:{{entity.entityfield}}</div>
```

for Users:

```
<div class="{{nodeClass}} capsule">{{user.username}}:{{user.userfield}}</div>
```

how would you structure the code and with which angularjs elements (ng-repeat etc) to (re)use the correct templates based on the value of "nodeClass". Keep in mind that I don't want to make a new conditional template except if it is the only solution.

Edit: I have found those approaches: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/ and [if else statement in AngularJS templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810278/if-else-statement-in-angularjs-templates) and [Dynamically displaying template in ng-repeat directive in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155542/dynamically-displaying-template-in-ng-repeat-directive-in-angularjs) but they are quite different than my requirements. Especially the last one is the closest to what I want but my templates as usually have different variable names in them..

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected structure for the overall view? or will it be multiple views? Not clear what your expectations are and that would help determine best approach

Comment: In the order they come in separate (different) divs based on their respective templates. The selection of template should be based on the property "nodeClass"

Comment: how many templates are we dealing with?

Comment: apologies if my answer seemed premature..these comments weren't showing for some reason.

Comment: Some update as I was wrong up there. My templates also expect different variable names :/ - (btw this a very simplified version of my problem) - Thanks :)

Comment: Based on edits in question you need to be more specific then why those other solutions don't fit your needs. And should have pointed out what you already knew so we didn't waste time doing the same things. You can use a directive for this but not sure what the complications or expectations are

Comment: ok my bad. but if that was the case then my question would be duplicate of the last one - editted

Comment: @MichailMichailidis What do you mean by `different variable names`? The templates use `thing` or `entity` instead of `item` sometimes? Why can you not use the same variable name as what`ng-repeat` uses in all templates?

Comment: You are not making your point as to what makes your situation different. We can't guess at what you are trying to match with your templates. Somehow you need to make a relationship between the nodeClass and template and there are lots of ways to do the matching in the code

Comment: @sgwatstack that's exactly what I mean. Well I cannot just change it in a hundred places..

Comment: Change What? you haven't shown us a sample of template names structure.

Comment: @MichailMichailidis So you already have 100s of templates which all have different variable names in them and you want to be able to stick them in `ng-repeat`s no matter what variable name the `ng-repeat` is using?

Comment: @charlietfl I agree about the mapping between nodeClass property and paths - that is very easy. There are many ways as you said. But the question comes down to: is there something like this syntax so I can use my existing templates that have different variables

```ng-repeat="elem in data" ng-conditional-rename=" "```

Comment: @sgwatstack yes! Bad practice or not I need to reuse my existing templates (that are just 6) but are used in many many places

Comment: sure...can use a directive...but still have to manually enter all those renames in html or in a hashmap

Comment: yeah that is not a big problem @charlietfl

Comment: so any of these other solutions would work exactly the same as directive would...you need to map the templates to the nodeClass values. There is no simple way out

Comment: I agree - I know all those solutions. As I said the problem is that I am not trying to make a conditional template but reuse existing ones and the mapping is not the issue but the variable name is

Comment: @MichailMichailidis what about parsing the template and doing a string replace - then return the url from `getContentUrl(objType)` to include it in the repeater. Or you could perform the string replace and insert the template into the DOM and then run `$compile(DOMElement)` on it.

Comment: (Upvote) that seems like a good idea although a bit hacky. Would you mind giving me a small example?

Comment: should note that this whole question got littered with a fairly significant number of comments...usually a sign that things weren't clear from the start

Comment: @MichailMichailidis I added a functioning solution. It's not pretty and there is plenty of work for you left to do, but it's a proof of concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try pulling the `template.html` in the background via `$http`, parse the template and replace instances of the variable name that doesn't match your `ng-repeat` variable name. Then send that `html` from the `template.html` to a directive (or controller template) that has the `ng-repeat` in its template, insert the newly edited html via `$('#elem').html(newHtml);` and call `$compile` on the modified element.

The template you pull down could look like this

`controller1/template1.html`

```
<h1>{{item.data}} - {{item.name}}</h1>
```

Here is the template that the repeater sits in

`controller1.html`

```
<p>This is the view for controller 1.</p>

<div id="repeater" ng-repeat="thing in vm.items">

</div>
```

The fetching of the template, replacing of the desired string and re-compiling of the template can be done like this

`controller1.js`

```
function Controller1($scope, $http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.items = [{name: 'item1', data: 123}, {name: 'item2', data: 456}];

    var templateReplacement = '{{thing.';
    $http.get('controller1/template1.html')
        .then(function success(response) {
            var newHtml = response.data.replace(/{{item./g, templateReplacement);
            var repeaterElem = $('#repeater');

            $(repeaterElem[0]).html(newHtml);

            $compile(repeaterElem)($scope);
    }, function failure(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
    });
}
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IBDAMB) of this working in action

Comment: Although it is missing the conditional/mapping logic - this will work - so I am accepting the answer - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use a dynamically generated `ng-include` url

HTML

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div ng-include="getContentUrl(item.nodeClass)"></div>
  </div>
```

Templates

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/Entity.html">
    <h3>Entity Template , text= {{item.text}}</h3>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/User.html">
    <h3>User Template , username ={{item.username}}</h3>
  </script>
```

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data=[{"nodeClass":"Entity", "text":"foo"},{"nodeClass":"User","username":"bar"}];
  $scope.getContentUrl = function(nodeClass){
    return 'partials/'+nodeClass +'.html';
  }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dSEdtibncXEcswWppQJs?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: (Upvoted) Ok that is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155542/dynamically-displaying-template-in-ng-repeat-directive-in-angularjs
but my templates have different variable names.. is there a solution for that as well?

Comment: not until you make your issues more definitive, Can easily make a hash map for the template paths vs nodeClass

Comment: @MichailMichailidis could you include the template name along with the data object definition in the json as a standard property name among all the varying objects? ie `{ template: "xyz.html", nodeClass: "className" ... }`

Comment: The issue is that contrary to your solution and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155542/dynamically-displaying-template-in-ng-repeat-directive-in-angularjs my templates don't have a common variable name e.g ```item``` - but distinct ones - I updated the original question multiple times and I guess you have gotten the updates before submission. Thanks

Comment: @sgwatstack I don't see why this would help my problem

Comment: @charlietfl yeah I could even use a switch case statement in the getContentUrl(). But this still doesn't solve the issue of two comments above

Answer (score 1):

I built a directive which takes two attributes - one for the template and the other for whatever data you need to pass in to the template.

Pass your template selector value through a switch statement which then will apply the correct template and sort your data appropriately.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/74rLIF71J7aPfnviYiLv?p=preview)

Directive:

```
app.directive('templateSelector', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
      console.log(attr.tClass, attr.tVals)
      var template ='';
      scope.data = angular.fromJson(attr.tVals);
      switch (attr.tClass) {
        case 'Entity':
          template = '<div><h1>Entity Class Template</h1>{{data.text}}</div><hr/>';
          break;
        case 'User':
          template = '<div><h1>User Class Template</h1>{{data.username}}</div><hr/>';
          break;
      }
      $template = angular.element(template);
      $compile($template)(scope);
      el.append($template); 
    }  
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="d in dataset">
    <div template-selector t-class="{{d.nodeClass}}" t-vals="{{d}}"></div>      
</div>
```

Comment: No worries for the premature answer. But this renders all the values and doesn't use predefined (different) templates

Comment: one for each of the different nodeClasses - In my real case around 6. In this case 2

Comment: is this the structure of the dataset?  Just a template selector and a value you  need to display?

Comment: it is a set of values and a property that differentiates the template to be used

Comment: see if that solution works for you.  I had included templates inside the directive itself, but if you have more complex datasets and templates you would definitely want to abstract those out of the directive.  You can just have the switch function set the templateUrl value as show in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl

Comment: hate to say this but using switch is uglier than alternatives like using a hashmap when there will be many of these

Comment: @tpie thanks for your effort. This solution doesn't use included templates from a file but that is minor. The major problem is that in this solution as well as on the other proposed ones the variable is the same and in my templates the variable names are distinct.

Comment: @charlietfl switch, hash or if else or path naming convention - that is minor ;)

Comment: @charlietfl - he said about 6...not that many.

I am slightly confused though.  You say the variable is the same, but in your templates the variable names are distinct.  I am not following what you mean here.

Comment: @tpie I mean I have a template with entity, a template with user variable etc.. And I have pages that use them in this fashion ng-repeat over users using the variable user, entity etc.. the templates are 6 in my real case the pages are many and I don't want to make them all use element/item..

Comment: are you saying that in the templates you want it to dynamically display the data, without having to put in specific bindings like {{data.username}}?

Answer (score 1):

I might modify the data from the service before it ever reaches the view. This works by using ng-if to determine which HTML to display:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataset">
  <div
    class="capsule"
    ng-class="data.nodeClass"
    ng-bind="data.text"
    ng-if="data.nodeClass==='Entity'"></div>
  <div
    class="capsule"
    ng-class="data.nodeClass"
    ng-bind="data.username"
    ng-if="data.nodeClass==='User'"></div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/shrKgktkxIvy9BhH5wfo?p=preview) Forked from tpie

Comment: what about the rest of the values of the objects? Also I think ng-bind is working with inputs only. How would I use external template files?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis `ng-bind="variable"` is the same as `{{variable}}`

Comment: @charlietfl you are right on this one - I just didn't know since I don't use them as they are more verbose compared to  ```{{variable}}``` except for inputs that I have to.