# data-ng-repeat with different tags in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following variable in Angular controller:

```
$scope.items = [
  { title: 'x', type: 'x'},
  { title: 'y', type: 'y'}
];
```

You can see only 2 items in array, but they will be more. So, I need to 'render' this array in HTML. I can use ng-repeat Angular directive, but there is some problem: if item has type 'x' I must render  for it, if y -  for it. How can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if item has type 'x'` then what?

Comment: what you tried in html?

Comment: You could check the `type` in the `ng-repeat` body, and load a template/view based on whether it's `x` or `y`? or just use a directive and pass the type and let that decide which template to load. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155542/dynamically-displaying-template-in-ng-repeat-directive-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Use a commbination of `ng-repeat` and `ng-switch`:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { title: "TestX", type: "x" },
    { title: "TestY", type: "y" }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ item.title }}
    <div ng-switch="item.type">
      <div ng-switch-when="x">
        HTML for type x
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="y">
        HTML for type y
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place a `:filter` in the `ng-repeat`, like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    title: 'x',
    type: 'x'
  }, {
    title: 'y',
    type: 'y'
  }, , {
    title: 'another x',
    type: 'x'
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <div>Only items of type 'x':</div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {type: 'x'} ">{{item.title}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ng-hide which hides element if expression is true

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" >
        <div ng-hide="item.type == 'y'">
        {{ item.type }}
        </div>
        <div ng-hide="item.type == 'x'">
        {{ item.type }}
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render only for item type `x` then can user 'filter' in `ng-repeat` or can use `ng-if`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"> 
    <div ng-if="item.type==='x'">
       <p>Item for type x</p>
    </div>
</div>
```